# How to run job on least loading nodes?

Tags: slurm

In our environment, we set slurm run jobs according load with following configuration in slurm.conf

```
SelectTypeParameters=CR_LLN,CR_CPU
PartitionName=all Nodes=video[0-15],hc[0-29] Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE     State=UP LLN=YES
```

However, when submitting jobs, slurm always chooses node in default order, not by its current loading. (even there are running jobs causes high load in that node).

How to make slurm aware machine loading and run jobs on least loading nodes ?

Comment: Are weights defined for your nodes in `slurm.conf`? If so they take precedence.